# javascript addEventListener - garbage collection

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, event-listener

If I create an artificial number of audios, add event-listeners to each of them and never remove them, do I have a memory leak?

```
/* creates infinite number of audios
* note: while(true) would freeze the browser */
function createAudio() {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.addEventListener("waiting", function(event) {
        console.log("will never execute");
    });
    window.setTimeout(createAudio, 0);
}

createAudio();
```

Answer (score 0):

For most of the browser today it has a built-in garbage collector a form of automatic memory management. It collect memory that is occupied by the objects and its no longer used by the programs.

This articles here provide a better understanding of how javascript do the job http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science) to better understand the term garbage-collection.